# Random lockups with my new build

Tags: graphics-card, timing, voltage

I have been having random lockups with my new build. The game will lock up, then the monitor refreshes and it goes back to normal... Lowering the graphic settings helped significantly in WoW, but now in starcraft 2 the lockups happen every 3 minutes or so on low settings.

I thought it was my graphics card, but when I called XFX they thought otherwise. They thought it could be a memory issue and suggested checking my timings and voltage settings. My Timing was listed as 8-8-8-20 and under "DRAM Voltage" was listed at 1.5v.

According to Newegg the timing is 8-8-8-24-2N, and the Voltage is 1.6V. I really hate messing around in my bios, so I wanted to see what you guys thought.

Specs:
Gigabyte X58 UD3R rev.2.0 bios version F
i7 930
XFX Radeon 5850
G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 6GB (3 x 2GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model F3-12800CL8T-6GBRM
Corsair CMPSU-750TX 750-Watt TX Series 80 Plus

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Timing is not that much lower. But I would manually set your voltage to 1.6 first and see if that clears it up.

Comment: Changed the Voltage, and its still happens -- but far less frequently. I also have the video settings set to Ultra, so it definitely made a difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Go into the timing and change it from 20 to 24